# Присваивание классов блокам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код, который при нажатии на `<div>` присваивает ему `class`

```js
$(".element").click(function() {
  $(".element").addClass("text");
});
```

```html
<div class="element">Блок с контентом</div>
```

Если `<div>` один, то все прекрасно работает, но если блоков несколько, то появляются проблемы. `class` присваивается всем блокам. Как можно присваивать `class` только тому блоку, на который я нажал? У всех блоков изначально одинаковый класс, потому что их выводит скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в jquery можно использовать this - берет именно тот элемент на котором сработало собитие

```js
$(".element").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("text");
});
```

```css
.text{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">Блок с контентом</div>
<div class="element">Тест блок</div>
```

Comment: О, отлично, спасибо.

Comment: А можно как-то удалять этот класс по повторному нажатию? Я пробую использовать removeClass, но я не могу получить для функции класс, когда он через пробел.

Comment: @erm, обновил ответ

Comment: Идеально, спасибо :)

Comment: @erm, спасибо и вам)